# Error on try to post file from Angular 6 to ASP.NET Core Web Api

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to do a POST request with multipart/form-data from an Angular 6 application to a REST service in ASP.NET Core, but I have a Error 500. I tried too many solutions, but nothing worked. I tried to execute the request on Postman and get the same problem, but I tried in other software called ARC (Advanced REST Client) and works like a charm and I don't have any idea why.

On the server-side, I getting InvalidDataException: Missing content-type boundary. In my project, I'm using swagger too

here is my code

The request in angular:

```
public uploadPlanilha(planilha: File, idLote: number): Observable<Array<RequisicaoComposicao>>{
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('arquivo', planilha, planilha.name);
    formData.append('idLote', idLote.toString());

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

    return this.httpClient.post<Array<RequisicaoComposicao>>(`${this.API_URL}requisicoes/upload`, formData, {
      headers: httpHeaders
    });
  }
```

The controller method in Web Api

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("upload")]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        [DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public ActionResult<List<RequisicaoComposicao>> PostPlanilhaRequisicoes([FromForm]ArquivoDto arquivoDto)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Stream arquivoPlanilha = arquivoDto.Arquivo.OpenReadStream())
                {
                    List<RequisicaoComposicao> requisicaoComposicoes = _composicaoGestor.Inserir(arquivoPlanilha, int.Parse(arquivoDto.IdLote));
                    return Ok(requisicaoComposicoes);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

The ArquivoDto class

```
public class ArquivoDto
        {
            public IFormFile Arquivo { get; set; }
            public string IdLote { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: `HttpHeaders` is immutable, you need to set the header like `let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data").set("Accept", "multipart/form-data");` otherwise each time you call `set` a new instance of `HttpHeaders` is returned and your previous header is overwritten . That's why you are not getting the `content-type` header at the server.

Comment: I changed this, but still not working. I tried with Content-Type on header and tried without this parameter too, but anything worked.

Comment: try to use it like `let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")` , you can't re-assign the httpHeaders variable.

Comment: Also if you are using `[FromForm]` then the Content-Type should be `application/x-www-url-formencoded` , but if you only want to post the file then remove `[FromForm]` and use `(IFormFile arquivoDto)` as the parameter, the content-type should be `multipart/form-data` in this case

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[FromForm]` tag you don't need it.

On this line here:
`formData.append('arquivo', planilha, planilha.name);`

change it to `formData.append('arquivo', planilha);`

I never used it, therefore I don't think you need the `[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]` attribute ether. (unless you are using something like swagger and you want to tell it what this method is consuming then keep it)

I'd also remove this line `httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set("Accept", "multipart/form-data");`

Comment: I'm using swagger. I removed the codes that you suggested, but still not working.

Comment: try to remove the `httpHeaders = httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");` line as well.

Comment: I tried this too. Now, I get error 500. In the backend, the error is: System.IO.InvalidDataException: Missing content-type boundary

Comment: @ViníciusdaCruzMaia check my comment above

Answer (score 0):

I use AngularJS + ASP.NET Core 2.1 and find the same error --> `System.IO.InvalidDataException: Missing content-type boundary`.

My solution is setting `'Content-Type: undefined'` in http request front-end. I read somewhere at StackOverflow, you may give it a quick try if it helps.